# How do I abbreviate a string using substring(int,int);

Tags: java

System.out.print(str.substring(0,5));
In this case, it will abbreviate the input to the 5th character. But when I input strings that are less than 5 characters, an error is produced. I want the code to abbreviate to the 5th character but keep anything less than 5 characters in its original format.
So if the input was "Cat", I would want the output to be "Cat". But if the input was "Mathematics", I want the output to be "Mathe". So anything less than 5 characters is outputted normally, but anything above 5 is abbreviated to the 5th character.

Comment: I assume you have learned to use `if`, so think about your problem:  “If and only if the string’s length is greater than 5, shorten it by calling substring.”  The words of that statement practically are the code you want to write.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a substring with *at most* 5 chars of length, this will do the trick:

```
str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
str.substring(0,Math.min(str.length(), 5))
```

Comment: My exact same answer...

Comment: yeah, I saw, seems we posted at the same time, it's a very straightforward answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez which honestly has been answered a million times here

Comment: Answers should also explain why.